# Yii CGridView renders a new page instead of AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, yii

In the index page of my site I have floating div-block with CGridView inside.

I need to use sort, filter, paging etc. options, but only via updating this only div and not refreshing the whole page.

Data rendering as it should, i'm stuck only with updating grid contents - all `<a>`'s have href, that sending user to specified view.

Here's the view for grid: (it's the only content of my views.users.usersGrid.php)

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'ajaxUrl' => 'modules/subcntrl/usersGrid',
    'ajaxUpdate' => 'users-grid',
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->name)'
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

It's called from views.users.users.php: `<?php $this->actionUsersGrid(); ?>`

Controller:

```
public function actionUsers() {
    $this->renderPartial('users');
}

public function actionUsersGrid() {
    if(!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) die('Url should be requested via ajax only');
    $model = new Users();
    $this->renderPartial('usersGrid',array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: what do you mean by "It's called from views.users.users.php: <?php $this->actionUsersGrid(); ?>"

Comment: ...so not sure I can help you with the Ajax request itself, but it appears to me that instead of calling `<?php $this->actionUsersGrid(); ?>` on `users.php`, you have to put `renderPartial('usersGrid'...` on there and name your `ajaxUrl` something completely different, eg. `ajaxCall`, then in the controller, get rid of `actionUsersGrid`, and name it `actionAjaxCall` (of course, depending on how you named the `ajaxUrl`), and setup your ajax actions there...

Comment: That's the line inside users.php where gridview is being placed. Like this: `some_text <div id="users-grid"><?php $this->actionUsersGrid(); ?></div>`

Comment: i just edited my comment... basically you're calling it the wrong way... the reason I only added it as a comment is because I won't be able to help you with the ajax call, but the way the view is setup is definitely incorrect...

Comment: code is changed a little bit after some attempts and tuts i found on this to make it work. i had users and usersGrid in a single file before, built via `renderPratial('usersGrid',array('model'=>$model))` so there wasn't this call, but it was working the same way as now. ok, thank you, i'll try to change this part as you commented and'll let you know

Comment: think i've found the reason. this view was called from another view rendered by renderpartial with processOutput set to true, so none JS was added to output and so, i have to look the other place of answer :( thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: happy i could drive you closer to a solution... hopefully ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use the third and fouth parameter in `renderPartial` method like this,

```
$this->renderPartial('users',array(),false,true);
```

it will solve your problem (setting the `processOutput=true` ) in the fourth parameter

Comment: I'm using it in parent view and i've tried it here too, but no effect. Take a look at my last comment for the question :)

Answer (score 0):

please use the third and fouth parameter in renderPartial method like this,

```
$this->renderPartial('users',array(),false,true);
```

it will solve your problem (setting the `processOutput=true` ) in the fourth parameter

this is not working in my code. i am using like this in ma controler

```
$this->renderPartial('_searchQuote', array('model' => $model, 'month' => $month, 'user' => $user), false, $processOutput=false );
```